# Mocking URLSession for API Testing is giving unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift, testing, mocking, nsurlsession

I want to test an API without making a server call so I am mocking URLSession and URLSessionDataTask so that I can inject it in my API class.

```
 class MockURLSession: URLSession {
    private let mockTask: MockTask
    var cachedUrl: URL?


    init(data: Data?, urlResponse: URLResponse?, error: Error?) {
        mockTask = MockTask(data: data, urlResponse: urlResponse, error:
            error)
    }

    override func dataTask(with url: URL, completionHandler: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void) -> URLSessionDataTask {

        self.cachedUrl = url
        mockTask.completionHandler = completionHandler
        return mockTask
    }
}

class MockTask: URLSessionDataTask {
    private let data: Data?
    private let urlResponse: URLResponse?
    var completionHandler: ((Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void)!

    init(data: Data?, urlResponse: URLResponse?, error: Error?) {
        self.data = data
        self.urlResponse = urlResponse
    }

    override func resume() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.completionHandler(self.data, self.urlResponse, self.error)
        }
    }
}
```

Here when I am running this test it's going in my API class calling the getMovies method. Instance I am getting over there is kind of MockURLSession which is fine. Next moment it gives this ApiTests testGetMoviesSuccessReturnsMovies] : failed: caught "NSInvalidArgumentException", "-[MyAppTests.MockTask error]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600002010500

```
func testGetMoviesSuccessReturnsMovies() {
        let jsonData = "[{\"title\": \"Spider Man Far From Home\",\"detail\": \"The first Spider-Man featuring Tom Holland in the iconic role\"}]".data(using: .utf8)
        var mockURLSession  = MockURLSession(data: jsonData, urlResponse: nil, error: nil)
        let apiRespository = APIRepository(session: mockURLSession)
        let moviesExpectation = expectation(description: "movies")
        var moviesResponse: Result<[Movie]>?

        apiRespository.getMovies { (movies) in
            moviesResponse = movies
            moviesExpectation.fulfill()
        }
        waitForExpectations(timeout: 10) { (error) in
            XCTAssertNotNil(moviesResponse)
        }
}
```

Here is my protocol extension for api

```
extension Gettable {

    func get<T:Decodable>(with decodingType: T.Type, url: String, session: URLSession, completion:@escaping(Result<T>) -> Void) {

        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!) { (data, response, error) in
             guard data != nil && error == nil  else {
                return
            }
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let parsedObj = try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data ?? Data())
                completion(Result.success(parsedObj))
            }
            catch let parsedError {
                completion(Result.failure(parsedError))
            }
        }
        dataTask.resume()
    }
}
```

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not overriding the method `dataTask(with:completionHandler:)` in your `MockURLSession`. So, the original `dataTask(with:completionHandler:)` of `URLSession` is called, which internally calls `dataTaskForRequest:completion:`.

If you are successfully overriding existing methods in the parent class, Swift compiler claims to prefix `override` keyword.

Move your nested `dataTask(with:completionHandler:)` out of `init(data:urlResponse:error:)`.

```
init(data: Data?, urlResponse: URLResponse?, error: Error?) {
    mockTask = MockTask(data: data, urlResponse: urlResponse, error:
        error)
}

override func dataTask(with url: URL, completionHandler: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void) -> URLSessionDataTask {

    self.cachedUrl = url
    mockTask.completionHandler = completionHandler
    return mockTask
}
```

---

For edited part...

Seems inheritance of `error` property is not working properly. (Which may be a bug of Swift compiler related to bridging `NSError` and `Error`.)

Please try this:

```
class MockTask: URLSessionDataTask {
    private let data: Data?
    private let urlResponse: URLResponse?

    private let _error: Error?
    override var error: Error? {
        return _error
    }

    var completionHandler: ((Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void)!

    init(data: Data?, urlResponse: URLResponse?, error: Error?) {
        self.data = data
        self.urlResponse = urlResponse
        self._error = error
    }

    override func resume() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.completionHandler(self.data, self.urlResponse, self.error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good catch! I think I messed up with brackets and complier asked me to fix and remove that override keyword as it was with in init and I was wondering why can't I override that method. I fixed it still getting error and I updated my question. Thanks for help and can you re-check.

Comment: @ShehzadAli, I have added some code, please try. By the way, you should better not re-write your question completely. My old answer has no meaning with your edited question. Just ADD some new info or start a new thread.